# PASCAL Annotation Version 1.00 conversion to pascal VOC

Tags: image-processing, annotations, crop, pascal

I have bounding box of image annotation data set which has .txt format using PASCAL annotation version 1. I would like to convert this to pascal voc format. is there a tool for that?
My intention is that i want to cut the images based on the bounding boxes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this q is off-topic at SO because it seems to be asking for a tool recommendation and/or a "how-to" tutorial.  You might do better to ask [here](https://en.delphipraxis.net/).

Comment: Please specify the Pascal compiler that you use.